# Error when creating an image from a UIView

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiimage

I'm creating an image from a view whith the folowing code :

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(myView.bounds.size);    
[myView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(viewImage, nil, nil, nil);
```

The image is created in the user album but in the consol I get this :

```
2010-05-11 10:17:17.974 myApp[3875:1807] sqlite error 8 [attempt to write a readonly database]
2010-05-11 10:17:18.014 myApp[3875:1807] Backtrace for sqlite error: (0x34e3a909 0x34e3d87f 0x34e3b029 0x34e3b22b 0x34e2f48b 0x34e2dccb 0x34e2d2f7 0x34e2d3bb 0x34e4dcd3 0x34e50515 0x34e51351 0x34e51681 0x34e513f5 0x34e511e3 0x303af57c 0x34e51163 0x303b06e8 0x303ac8e0 0x303ac6d8 0x303ac8c8 0x303aca80 0x30350d55 0x3034a12c)

2010-05-11 10:17:18.077 myApp[3875:1807] sqlite error 8 [attempt to write a readonly database]
2010-05-11 10:17:18.087 myApp[3875:1807] Backtrace for sqlite error: (0x34e3a909 0x34e3b053 0x34e3b22b 0x34e2f48b 0x34e2dccb 0x34e2d2f7 0x34e2d3bb 0x34e4dcd3 0x34e50515 0x34e51351 0x34e51681 0x34e513f5 0x34e511e3 0x303af57c 0x34e51163 0x303b06e8 0x303ac8e0 0x303ac6d8 0x303ac8c8 0x303aca80 0x30350d55 0x3034a12c)

2010-05-11 10:17:18.091 myApp[3875:1807] sqlite error 8 [attempt to write a readonly database]
2010-05-11 10:17:18.095 myApp[3875:1807] Backtrace for sqlite error: (0x34e3a909 0x34e3b085 0x34e3b22b 0x34e2f48b 0x34e2dccb 0x34e2d2f7 0x34e2d3bb 0x34e4dcd3 0x34e50515 0x34e51351 0x34e51681 0x34e513f5 0x34e511e3 0x303af57c 0x34e51163 0x303b06e8 0x303ac8e0 0x303ac6d8 0x303ac8c8 0x303aca80 0x30350d55 0x3034a12c)

2010-05-11 10:17:18.111 myApp[3875:1807] sqlite error 1 [SQL logic error or missing database]
2010-05-11 10:17:18.115 myApp[3875:1807] Backtrace for sqlite error: (0x34e3a909 0x34e3d87f 0x34e3b029 0x34e3b4dd 0x34e2f48b 0x34e2dccb 0x34e2d2f7 0x34e2d3bb 0x34e4dcd3 0x34e50515 0x34e51351 0x34e51681 0x34e513f5 0x34e511e3 0x303af57c 0x34e51163 0x303b06e8 0x303ac8e0 0x303ac6d8 0x303ac8c8 0x303aca80 0x30350d55 0x3034a12c)

2010-05-11 10:17:18.120 myApp[3875:1807] sqlite error 1 [SQL logic error or missing database]
2010-05-11 10:17:18.124 myApp[3875:1807] Backtrace for sqlite error: (0x34e3a909 0x34e3b053 0x34e3b4dd 0x34e2f48b 0x34e2dccb 0x34e2d2f7 0x34e2d3bb 0x34e4dcd3 0x34e50515 0x34e51351 0x34e51681 0x34e513f5 0x34e511e3 0x303af57c 0x34e51163 0x303b06e8 0x303ac8e0 0x303ac6d8 0x303ac8c8 0x303aca80 0x30350d55 0x3034a12c)

2010-05-11 10:17:18.129 myApp[3875:1807] sqlite error 1 [cannot commit - no transaction is active]
2010-05-11 10:17:18.133 myApp[3875:1807] Backtrace for sqlite error: (0x34e3a909 0x34e3b085 0x34e3b4dd 0x34e2f48b 0x34e2dccb 0x34e2d2f7 0x34e2d3bb 0x34e4dcd3 0x34e50515 0x34e51351 0x34e51681 0x34e513f5 0x34e511e3 0x303af57c 0x34e51163 0x303b06e8 0x303ac8e0 0x303ac6d8 0x303ac8c8 0x303aca80 0x30350d55
```

I don't know where the problem come from. 
Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell you why you get the "readonly" messages, but I can tell you that this is not normal: I just tried out UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(anImg,nil,nil,nil) on an iPod Touch with OS 3.1.3. and it generated the file in the photos DB without such any msgs in the Console.

This could indicate that you have a defective photos db. Try erasing your photos on the device, or do even a clean re-install, without any of your old data, and see if that makes the problem go away. If yes, you photo DB may have been corrupted somehow.